# Integrate C++ documentation into docusaurus

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, docusaurus

I have a large code base that I do want to document with docusaurus. I used doxygen for the project before but I like docusaurus more now. Is there a way to integrate the C++ functions/classes/methods into docusaurus without having to manually write the function signatures by hand?

I did a lot of googling and one possibility would be to still generate the signatures with doxygen and include the generated files in the /static folder of docusaurus. What I don't like about this solution is that the styling of the website would break, everything should stay in the styling of docusaurus and not doxygen.

Did anyone had a similar problem before and could help me out? :D

Comment: FYI: [Doxygen: Customizing the output](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html). (I guess you are already aware of this.) A crazy idea, if you intent to solve this on your own: Use Doxygen to generate XML output. Write an XSLT to convert XML to MD. Use MD files in Docusaurus. (I must admit that I'm using Doxygen for a while but heard the 1st time about Docusaurus.) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! I will continue searching for better solutions but if I don't find anything I will probably follow your suggestion. I would prefer a single tool that can generate the API docs and where you have the option to input your own MD files for architecture documentation :)